# what's the point of % before line breaks?

Tags: sourcecode, percent-sign

I see this pattern of `%`(s) before line-breaks a lot in packages. What's the point of it? Is it necessary or a convention? For example:

```tex
\newenvironment{blah}{%
  some command%
  some other command%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is usually to avoid unwanted horizontal spaces.

Comment: try typesetting your example you will get "some commandsome other command"  with no word space.